# Javascript ajax queue system needed. Cross domain jsonp. How would i do this.

Tags: javascript, ajax, queue, jsonp

I have this javascript code which i want to change into a queue system. Currently i am having to code it like this.  It becomes messy when there are a long chain of requests. 
Note: My functions requests return json objects.
      Setting async to false is not used for cross domain jsonp calls so wont work.
      Calls have to be made in this order.
      Jquery queues wont work.

```
var customers;
var orders;
var products;
function GetCustomers(){
            $.ajax({
                url: somecrossdomainurl?calback=GetCustomerCallback,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                async: false
            });
}

function GetCustomerCallback(data){
            customers=data;
            GetCustomersOrder();
        }

function GetCustomersOrder(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: somecrossdomainurl?calback=GetCustomersOrderCallback,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    async: false
                });
        }

function  GetCustomersOrderCallback(data){
    orders = data;
    GetOrderProducts();
}

function GetOrderProducts(){
        $.ajax({
            url: somecrossdomainurl?calback=GetOrderProductsCallback,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false
        });
}

function  GetOrderProductsCallback(data){
    products = data;
    DisplayCustomersAndOrder();
}

function DisplayCustomersAndOrder(){
    //loop round customer,order,products and display info
}


//I want to do something like this:

function DisplayData(){
    var queue;

    queue.GetCustomer();
    queue.GetCustomersOrders();
    queue.GetOrderProducts();
    queue.DisplayCustomersAndOrder();
    queue.Start()
}
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Use jQuery's [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: Probably, it is a streamlined API, `$.ajax` always returns a promise object. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of an async queue using promises.
https://gist.github.com/thejuan/5697765

It's in TypeScript, but very little too do to change into pure JS.

It continues on error, if you dont want it to there are simpler solutions than this (just chain each of your calls by using then)

**Note:** Requires Jquery 1.8 or higher when they made *.then* behave "correctly"

```
export class AsyncExecutionQueue{

    private tail: JQueryPromise = $.Deferred().resolve();

    public enqueue(cmd:()=>any): JQueryPromise {

        console.log("Queuing Command");
        var next = $.Deferred();
        var client = $.Deferred();
        this.tail.always(() => {

            try {

                var result = cmd();
                if (result.done && result.fail) {
                    result
                    .done(client.resolve, next.resolve)
                    .fail(client.reject, next.resolve);
                }
                else {
                    client.resolve(result);
                    next.resolve();
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                client.reject(e);
                next.resolve();
            }
        });
        this.tail = next;
        return client;
    }
}
```